# See JSON returned by AJAX

Tags: json, ajax

Please see the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="Javascript/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSONExample.aspx/GetPerson",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess(),
            //async: false,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('there was an error counting possibles')
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess() {
            return function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        }
        }
        GetData()
    </script>
```

I believe response.d returns the desterilized JSON.  How do I see the JSON so that I can desterilize it myself into a .NET Object?

Comment: You will get a answer client side (Javascript). How could you use a .NET Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="Javascript/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSONExample.aspx/GetPerson",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            //async: false,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('there was an error counting possibles')
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
        GetData()
    </script>
```

Also, you can debug information with the developper tools of your Internet browser (F12 by default).

Comment: Thanks.  I have asked another similar question here in case you get chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549052/json-not-parsed-into-custom-object

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this code with yours, If you have printed the array in json format on this URL `JSONExample.aspx/GetPerson`

If you have not printed the array in json then below code will not work.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSONExample.aspx/GetPerson",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess(response),
            //async: false,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('there was an error counting possibles')
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            return function (response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
        }
        GetData()
    </script>
```

You will be able to see the response in console of your developer tool.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the reference to JSON.Convert.  
I have asked another similar question here in case you get chance: stackoverflow.com/questions/41549052/